# AutoMapper: Map object graph with multiple entry points?

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper

Say I have the following 3 types: Person, Company and Asset.

- Person has a collection of Assets.
- Company has a collection of Assets.
- Assets has no references.

Using these definitions, I create the following object instances:

- Person `P` has references to Assets `Aa` and `Ab`
- Company `C` has references to Assets `Ab` and `Ac`.

Note that the same object instance `Ab` is referenced by both `P` and `C`.

Now, I have 2 definitions of each of these types, and have defined mappings between them, e.g.:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Db.Person, Schema.Person>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Db.Company, Schema.Company>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Db.Assets, Schema.Assets>();
```

If I map `P` and `C` by calling `Mapper.Map` twice separately (like the code below), I get two separate object instances of `Ab`, one as part of `P` and one as part of `C`.

```
var mappedP = Mapper.Map<Schema.Person>(P);
var mappedC = Mapper.Map<Schema.Company>(C);
```

How do I get AutoMapper to map both `P` and `C` "at the same time" or using the same "context" of mapped objects, so that it does not create a mapped version of `Ab` twice, but rather reuses the same instance?

**Edit** To clarify, I'm using Entity Framework retrieve my object graph from the database.
Because of the shape of the data (i.e. multiple "root" objects), I need multiple database queries, but this is not an issue as long as these queries are executed against the same DbContext,  Entity Framework materializes every object only once.
Hence, this makes it possible to retrieve data shaped as described above with Person, Company and Asset - this works quite nicely.

I still need to massage this object graph in a format suitable to be returned from my service layer, but before I do that, I want AutoMapper to map the entire object graph from "Db" entities to "Schema" entities, so I can massage the data using the "Schema"-typed objects - hence my question.

I know that one workaround is to introduce an artificial container entity (in the example above, with Person and Company properties) that serves as the new single root object to be mapped.
However, this requires an extra class definition for every combination of multiple "root" objects that I want to map, which is not very elegant - I was wondering if there is a better way to have these kind of object graphs mapped?

**Edit 2**
The funny thing is that, within the scope of a call to `Mapper.Map()`, AutoMapper *already has* the behaviour of only mapping an object once, and reusing the same mapped instance whenever the original object is encountered again.
I suspect that it keeps a mapping context (or "cache") of the instances already mapped (either explicitly or somewhere in the call stack), and that it is disposed before the call to `Mapper.Map()` returns.

If there were a way to make this mapping context explicit (e.g. by providing it as an argument to `Mapper.Map()`), this would solve my problem without risking memory leaks (the unreferenced cached instances will be disposed of when the mapping context loses scope).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit mental! :-)  Why do you want to achieve this?

If you were to create your own AssestsValueResolver

```
    public class AssestsValueResolver: IValueResolver
    {
        private Assests _assets;
    ...
    }
```

Then create the map each time before you map to Assests (not ideal for performance!)

```
var resolver = new AssestsValueResolver();
Mapper.CreateMap<Db.Assets, Schema.Assets>()
                    .ForAllMembers(
                        m => m.ResolveUsing<AssestsValueResolver>().ConstructedBy(() => resolver ));
```

You could cache the asset so the same instance is reused when you map to both Person and Customer and the same asset should be used (would you link them by ID?).

While this is potentially a solution (I've not tried it) can I ask again why you want to achieve this?

Can you not logically associate the same asset by ID?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have here is that while you have the same source Asset, you are creating a new destination Asset when you map.  How exactly is AutoMapper supposed to know that you've already mapped this Asset and that it should a) somehow find this Asset somewhere, and b) reuse it?

The problem is not so much identifying that you have the same asset (ie, using an ID or something), but rather keeping a cache of these assets.  When you cache objects, then the framework retains references to them, and then the garbage collector will not collect them, and you will have memory leaks.

So, in order to make this work, you need to create Weak references in your cache, so that you can look up the objects to see if they exist, and reuse them... if they don't create them.  This is not something that AutoMapper does itself, as it's not commonly needed functionality.

Honestly, this is error prone code that will probably need a lot of work to get right.  I would suggest finding alternate solutions if you can.  What's so bad about living with multiple copies of your source object?

Comment: See my second addition to the OP. For the time being, I've worked around this limitation by cutting up the object graph to be mapped into multiple disjoint graphs with one root. After having AutoMapper map each graph I then merge the results again. It's not ideal, but for now it works.

Comment: @Astrotrain - Yes, within the same map call, it does reuse the same instance.  In fact, this is commonly complained about behavior and there doesn't seem to be a good way to disable it.  You can find tons of questions here regarding that behavior.  I'm not sure I follow you though about the context.. that would basically mean you would have to keep track of the already mapped object yourself, and if you've already done that why bother mapping it again?